# Setting an exception for global <p> tag

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have set a global attribute to `<p>` to make the first letter of the paragraph a big, colorful letter. Now I have a `<p>` tag where I don't want that to happen. How can I add an exception to only 1 tag?

```
p::first-letter 
{
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #0565a8;
}
```

I am using the code above to get the effect that I want. Now I have a paragraph that I want to be plain and simple, without any effects.

```
<div id="next_event">
    <p style="padding-left: 5px;">Next event: 13.04</p>
</div>
```

And this is the paragraph where I want to have everything in plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `inherit` to set font-size and color of the parent element (parent of `p`).

```css
/* set style for paragraph first letter */
p::first-letter 
{
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #0565a8;
}


/* override the style for paragraph first letter, with the parent (inherit) style */
#next_event p::first-letter 
{
    font-size: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p>hello world</p>

<div id="next_event">
    <p>Next event: 13.04</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you maybe ellaborate on why your solution worked while the others propositions didn't?

Comment: @BogdanLazar Why you use an id? You cannot have the same id repeated in you DOM. You better off with something like this: `<p class="nofirstletter">Next event: 13.04</p>` and CSS `p.nofirstletter { font-size: inherit; color: inherit; }`

Comment: @BogdanLazar Added some comments to CSS. Please check [inherit documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit). Inherit is the correct way to "undo" properties.

Comment: ...Unless the property is inherited by default.

Comment: @HashemQolami That's correct. Which is the case for font-size and color.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:not()` selector.

Replace your CSS you applied before to this:

```
p:not(.someClass)::first-letter 
{
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #0565a8;
}
```

You can also replace `.someClass` with `#someId`

Comment: I don't know why, but this does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: If I change around your code, it has effect on ALL the tags in the code. Why?

Comment: Could you please explain what's wrong with my answer when you downvote?

Comment: @BogdanLazar that css statement is the only one you need. make sure you don't keep your original statement. this one replaces it completely

Comment: @Bog The CSS I provided should completely replace the CSS you had.

Comment: Oh, I now know why it didn't work before. I now understand the "not" tag. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is also a valid solution. @Downvoter care to explain? If it was because of lack of support in IE8 and below, forget it. Pre-historic IE users will not see the capital letter and that is not a big deal at all.

Comment: @nicael I'm not the downvoter, but this doesn't work unless he applies a class to his `p` element, which, surprisingly, you have yet to mention.

Answer (score 2):

I'd keep it simple if I were you, as you'll most likely be using a lot more plain `<p>` tags within your content than the decorative ones.

Rather than a special way of *not* targeting everything normal, why not use a class for the few instances of the decorative `<p>` tag?

```
p {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

p.decorative::first-letter {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #0565a8;
}
```

If you don't want padding on your decorative `<p>` tags, just change it to:

```
p.decorative::first-letter {
    padding-left:0;
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #0565a8;
}
```

If the decorative `<p>` tags are the rule rather than the exception, you could use @nicael's answer, and simply use the `:not()` selector.

Comment: Also a nice solution, but in some cases might not be convenient to populate the markup with a bunch of `<p class="decorative">` , if `p.decorative` is the rule and not the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a class to that particular paragraph tag and apply the necessary changes like this:

HTML:

```
<p class="no-effect">Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

CSS:

```
p.no-effect  {
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #333;
}
```

Make sure the `p.no-effect` css property is **below** your p global tag btw

Comment: This doesn't appear to be very flexible solution.

Comment: @nicael It depends on what we call it *flexible*. If supporting IE8 and below is a concern, the only way is to override the former declarations by using a new selector.

Comment: I don't know why, but this does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Try adding an `!important` tag to the properties under no-effect like this: `font-size: 100% !important;`

Answer (score 0):

```
:not(#next-event) > p::first-letter {
   font-size:100%;
   /*etc*/
}
```

You can use this anywhere you want, don't need to change your html markup